# Gulp refuses to compile scss files with @import in them

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have been working on a website and used Gulp to compile my scss files. However, the main.scss file quickly gained in the number of lines and I decided to split it in different files and then import into a single one which will be compiled to css.

here is the structure of my project (other folders, such as /js are omitted)

```
 - css
 - sass
    - helpers
      _variables.scss
    main.scss
```

I use the following line to import _variables.scss in my main.scss

```
@import 'helpers/_variables.scss';
```

this is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('sass',function(){
return gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
});
```

When I launch the task, here what CLI outputs:

```
[17:13:04] Starting 'sass'...
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    sass\main.scss
undefined
```

Comment: If I replace "@import 'helpers/_variable.scss';" with actual scss variables, everything works fine

Comment: I am sorry, that was a typo in the question. I am importing _variables.scss

Comment: If you compile this directly with Sass, rather than using Gulp, do you still get the same error?

Comment: Nope, It compiles just fine